# Use python requests to submit search forms

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I need to use requests to **scrape** some data from a website. The website is like `https://www.example.com/tele/search.php`. The website has a section like following:

```
<form action="search-result.php" method="post" name="sub">
    <label class="sr-only" for="usrname">Username</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">...</div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cnnum" placeholder="322112222 or 3520211114489" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger center-block" style="align-center ">Search</button>
</form>
```

So what I did was:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
S_URL = 'https://example.com/tele/search-result.php'
cnnum = '**********'
login_information = {
    'cnnum': cnnum
}

response = requests.post(S_URL, data=login_information)
print(response.content)
```

But it is not working and showing a not acceptable error. I am new to requests so kindly help. I do not want to use selenium. I want to do this with requests.

Comment: I suggest you don't get your "data" information from the page source (one reason stated [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7mz5l3/scraping_issue_why_is_inspect_element_different/dry4j7w/)). In your browser right click + inspect element and under the "Network" tab, you should see the post()/get() HTTP methods as they happen, then you can work from there

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow!` community, Kindly please share the url in order to be able to guide you for the `POST` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to locate the [website](https://simdatabaseonline.com/tele/search.php) which you referring to it, i do see that you are passing the correct method of `POST` request.

You didn't shared the `Errors` which you received yet. But i believe that you do have an issue with `response code` which is other than `200`,

So kindly be informed that website is hosted behind `CloudFlare` firewall protection which may block you if you made multiple `POST` requests as it's one of it's task to prevent browser automation.

Also consider to pass a valid `User-Agent`.

Below is a simple of the `POST` request.

```py
import requests

data = {'cnnum': '322112222'}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'}

r = requests.post("https://simdatabaseonline.com/tele/search.php", data=data)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks I got it already. I checked the network requests header. And by just introducing the useragent I was able to get status code 200. And this is not the website that I referred to but is a similar one.